# Reading on QRCodes on iOS with AVCaptureSession -- alignment issues?

Tags: ios, qr-code, avcapturesession

We have implemented a QRCode reading function in iOS using the AVCaptureSession class, as described nicely here:

https://github.com/HEmobile/ScanBarCode/tree/master/ScanBarCodes
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/

But one thing we notice... the QRCode has to be aligned exactly vertically or horizontally.  Oblique angles such as 45 degress does not trigger a scan.  This issue doesn't really google, which is surprising.

Our experiments with other QRcode reading apps indicate that this limitation does not exist.  Perhaps/seemingly (presumably -- since the built-in function is new) these apps don't use AVCaptureSession.

Our question is, is this a sign that Apple's version of this function is not mature yet?  Or is there some option to enable or improve this capability?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Maybe have a look on this repo https://github.com/erica/iOS-Gourmet-Cookbook/tree/master/C01%20-%20Media/03%20-%20QR%20Code%20Detection. Erica Sadun wrote a full chapter on QRCode and issues in her last book. Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you, but my question is whether this is an issue with this particular iOS API and how to deal with it, not necessarily QRCode.  Indeed I believe other QRCode readers don't have this trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've written some sort of limitation in your code. Check out my github repo: https://github.com/alexekoren/qr-3d

It was built specifically for reading QR Codes at angles in a pretty way. I'm testing it now and it pulls at 30-45 degrees easily.

Here's the direct link for everything you'll need to make the scanner object that can present on a UIView: https://github.com/AlexEKoren/QR-3D/blob/master/Code%20Scanner/Scanner/CSScanner.m

It should work out of the box!

Comment: Shoot... was excited to try it; I downloaded the zip, loaded the project, tried to build with XCode 6.4 and got the error "Linker command failed with exit code 1"... my least favorite error because (as far as I know) it just means the linker choked and it's not telling you where.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Let me have a quick look!

Comment: I'm happy to provide any more info if you tell me where to look.  The error message is "file not found: /Users/chrisrice/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Code_Scanner-cobobhynbrlayidaprzuxllzoqzn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Code Scanner.app/Code Scanner" but I presume that is just because the linker choked upstream, so nothing built.  just taking a stab, do your "ScannerTests" require something third party?

Comment: In the meantime having a look at your code, but nothing will motivate me more than seeing your App read at 45deg :)

Comment: I figured out the problem. Just redownload it now and it should work. Make sure the scheme at the top left says "QR 3D" and not "Code Scanner"

Comment: Also, check out the github repo now. I added two GIFs of it working. :)

Comment: Cool GIFs!  Will try it now.

Comment: Hm, same result.  Everything relevant seems to say "QR 3D", as you said.  Is there something I can check to make doubly sure I got your latest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88033/discussion-between-alexkoren-and-chris).

Comment: Forgive me if this turns out to be pilot error.  I wonder if it's trying to build "QR 3DTests" instead of "QR 3D".